# Filter Nested JSON Data in Python with Pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas

I am consuming a file that contains nested JSON data which I then convert to a pandas dataframe in order to filter the selection. The problem is that when it is converted to a pandas dataframe the column names become {parent}.{child} as dictated by the JSON structure. When I attempt to convert the dataframe back to JSON once the filter operation is done the nested structure of the JSON is lost and I am left with the below. Is it possible that when converting back to JSON that I don't lose the nested structure of the JSON?

```
with open('charts.json', 'r') as file:
    charts = json.load(file)
lineChart = pd.json_normalize(charts, "line_chart")
lineChartFiltered = lineChart.loc[lineChart['selection'] == 'Tom'].to_json(orient='records')
```

What lineChartFiltered currently produces:

```
'[{"selection":"Tom","speed.running":[{"x":1596153600000,"y":9.77,"color":"#1F8924"}]}]'
```

What I would prefer:

```
[{"selection":"Tom",
   speed: {
      running:[{
        x:123, 
        y: 23,
        cost: 244
      }]
}}]
```

Comment: The expected result is as noted above. Essentially I need the JSON to retain it's nested nature: [{"selection":"Tom",
   speed: {
      running:[{
        x:123, 
        y: 23,
        cost: 244
      }],      walking:[{
        x:13, 
        y: 223,
        cost: 24
      }]}}]. Rather than [{"selection":"Tom","speed.running":[{"x":123,"y":23,"cost":244}], "speed.walking":[{"x":13,"y":233,"cost":24}]}]

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that you can set the max parse level within json_normalize to ensure the dot notation is not used for nested JSON structures. This solved my problem:

```
linechart = pd.json_normalize(charts, "line_chart", max_level=0)
```